# know filename:line_no where an import to my_module was made

Tags: python, file, module, import

I have a module `my_module` that it is sourced (imported) by lots of files using:

`from my_module import *`

Being inside the module, can I know which file imported this module ?
I would like to know the filename:line_no which made this import.

so code I require is:

my_module.py

```
print "This module is currently imported from: file:line_no = %s:%s" % what_in_here??
```

Comment: Interesting, but why do you need this?

Answer (score 5):

Place this in your top-level module code:

```
import traceback
last_frame = traceback.extract_stack()[-2]
print 'Module imported from file:line_no = %s:%i' % last_frame[:2]
```

You can also use [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect-stack) instead of [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html):

```
import inspect
last_frame = inspect.stack()[1]
print 'Module imported from file:line_no = %s:%i' % last_frame[1:3]
```