# Overwrite import, show names of modules importing a module

Tags: python, python-import

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [know filename:line_no where an import to my_module was made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603321/know-filenameline-no-where-an-import-to-my-module-was-made)

I want to find out which modules are importing my sample module "foo":

foo.py

```
# pseudocode, this should be triggered when "foo" is imported
on_import():
    print "foo is imported by module X"
```

bar.py

```
# this should print "foo is imported by module bar"
import foo
```

How can I implement this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Wooble you are right

Here's the solution from [know filename:line_no where an import to my_module was made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603321/know-filenameline-no-where-an-import-to-my-module-was-made)

```
import inspect
last_frame = inspect.stack()[1]
print 'Module imported from file:line_no = %s:%i' % last_frame[1:3]
```